# Dynamic (not static) memory c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, malloc

What is the best way to create an array with undefined size? 
I have thousands of measures I need to put in an array. The values are provided by a sensor. So I can not know the size of my array only at the end; when the sensor stops emitting.

Am doing this

```
#define MAX_SIZE 100000000

double array[MAX_SIZE]
```

However, in addition of having more measures than MAX_SIZE, am getting this error message from the compiler:
: R_X86_64_32 against `.bss'`
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':

Is there a manner to not specificity or impose the initial (static) size of the pointer but let it grow automatically?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the perfect opportunity to use std::vector.

Comment: This is why you have collections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, the best option is to use an STL vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<double> v;

int main() {
    v.push_back(3.0); // Add an item
    v.push_back(5.0);
    v.push_back(7.0);
    v.push_back(8.0);

    cout << "v[0]: " << v[0] << endl; // Access an item
    cout << "v[1] + v[2]: " << v[1] + v[2] << endl;

    cout << "Size: " << v.size() << endl; // Size

    v.resize(2); // It will remove items except for the first two

    double sum = 0.0;

    vector<double>::iterator it;
    it = v.begin();
    while (it != v.end())
    {
        sum += *it;
        it++;
    }
    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;

    v.resize(0); // It will empty a vector

    cout << "Size: " << v.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It's a dynamic array which automatically extends when necessary. You are able to get items by index like from an array, iterate through it using iterators, clear it or resize.

Here you can read a reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best way is to use standard container `std::vector` with initial reserved memory.
You can also use its member function `max_size` to determine how many elements you can allocate in the vector.

For example the on-line MS VC++ compiler shows the following value 536870911:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v;

    std::cout << " max size = " << v.max_size() << std::endl;
}

Compiled with /EHsc /nologo /W4
main.cpp

Compilation successful!

Total compilation time: 187ms

 max size = 536870911

Total execution time: 531ms
```